# PrimeNg Organization Chart refresh programmatically

Tags: angular, primeng, orgchart

I am using p-organizationChart to display hierarchy. I am adding child dynamically. After adding child, it's not displaying expand arrow, but when I select any Node then it reflects.

So, I would like to refresh this org-chart programmatically.

Any suggestions?

```
 <p-organizationChart [value]="programStructure" styleClass="company" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedParentProgram" #chart [preserveSpace]="false">
</p-organizationChart>
```

Adding Child:

```
addChildNode() {
    this.selectedParentProgram.children.push({
        label: this.selectedChildProgram.name,
        type: 'node',
        expanded: true,
        data: {
            'programId': this.selectedChildProgram.id,
            'versionId': this.selectedProgramVersion.id
        },
        children: []
    });
    this.isAddProgramDialogShown = false;
    this.clear();
  }
```

This code works perfectly as expected. But, chart not getting updated unless I select/unselect any node.

**Solution Worked for me**

```
this.cd.detectChanges();
```

Comment: Please show how you are adding the child.

Comment: @MichaelD Added "Adding Child" code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular change detection is usually triggered when the reference to an object changes. Adding elements to an array using it's `push` method wouldn't change the array's reference. Instead you could try to re-assign the variable using the spread syntax.

Try the following

```js
addChildNode() {
  const child = {
    label: this.selectedChildProgram.name,
    type: 'node',
    expanded: true,
    data: {
      'programId': this.selectedChildProgram.id,
      'versionId': this.selectedProgramVersion.id
    },
    children: []
  };
  
  this.selectedParentProgram = {
    ...this.selectedChildProgram,
    children: [
      ...this.selectedChildProgram.children, 
      child
    ]
  };
  this.isAddProgramDialogShown = false;
  this.clear();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Based on above added below line of code and it worked. Thanks a lot.

this.cd.detectChanges();

Comment: @VaibhavSawant: Yes that would be the other alternative. To manually trigger the change detection when needed.